# VBscript to monitor system performance leaks memory

Tags: memory-leaks, vbscript

I have a simple script that monitors processes' different performance statistics in Windows XP in a loop until it is terminated.
Despite my efforts, the script's memory footprint increases in size over time.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
logFileDirectory = "C:\POSrewrite\data\logs"
Dim output
Dim filePath

filePath = "\SCOPerformance-" & Day(Now()) & Month(Now()) & Year(Now()) & ".log"

IF fso.FolderExists(logFileDirectory) THEN

ELSE
    Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(logFileDirectory)
END IF

logFilePath = logFileDirectory + filePath + ""

IF (fso.FileExists(logFilePath)) THEN
    set logFile = fso.OpenTextFile(logFilePath, 8, True)
    output = VBNewLine
    output = output & (FormatDateTime(Now()) + " Open log file." & VBNewLine)

ELSE
    set logFile = fso.CreateTextFile(logFilePath)
    output = output & (FormatDateTime(Now()) + " Create log file." & VBNewLine)
END IF

output = output & (FormatDateTime(Now()) + " Begin Performance Log data." & VBNewLine)
output = output & ( "(Process) (Percent Processor Time) (Working Set(bytes)) (Page Faults Per Second) (PrivateBytes) (PageFileBytes)" & VBNewLine)

WHILE (True)
    On Error Resume NEXT
    IF Err = 0 THEN 

        strComputer = "."
        Set objRefresher = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemRefresher")
        Set objServicesCimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" _
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set objRefreshableItem = _
            objRefresher.AddEnum(objServicesCimv2 , _
            "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process")
        objRefresher.Refresh
        ' Loop through the processes three times to locate  
        '    and display all the process currently using 
        '    more than 1 % of the process time. Refresh on each pass.

        FOR i = 1 TO 3

            objRefresher.Refresh 
            FOR Each Process in objRefreshableItem.ObjectSet
                IF Process.PercentProcessorTime > 1 THEN
                    output = output & (FormatDateTime(Now()) & "," &  i ) & _
                        ("," & Process.Name & _
                        +","  & Process.PercentProcessorTime & "%") & _
                        ("," & Process.WorkingSet) & ("," & Process.PageFaultsPerSec) & _
                        "," & Process.PrivateBytes & "," & Process.PageFileBytes & VBNewLine
                END IF
            NEXT
        NEXT
    ELSE
            logFile.WriteLine(FormatDateTime(Now()) + Err.Description)
    END IF
    logFile.Write(output)
    output = Empty
    set objRefresher = Nothing
    set objServicesCimv2 = Nothing
    set objRefreshableItem = Nothing
    set objFolder = Nothing
    WScript.Sleep(10000)
Wend
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the main problem with your script is that you initialize WMI objects inside the loop, that is, on every iteration of the loop, even though these objects are always the same:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objRefresher = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemRefresher")
Set objServicesCimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objRefreshableItem = _
    objRefresher.AddEnum(objServicesCimv2 , _
    "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process")
```

You need to move this code out of the loop, e.g., at the beginning of the script.

Other tips and suggestions:

- Use [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484.aspx) and explicitly declare all variables used in your script. Declared variables are slightly faster than undeclared ones.
- Use [`FileSystemObject.BuildPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) to combine multiple parts of the path. The useful thing about this method is that it inserts the necessary path separators for you.

  ```
  logFileDirectory = "C:\POSrewrite\data\logs"
  filePath = "SCOPerformance-" & Day(Now) & Month(Now) & Year(Now) & ".log"
  logFilePath = fso.BuildPath(logFileDirectory, filePath)
  ```
- The `objFolder` variable isn't used in your script, so there's no need to create it. Also, you can make the `FolderExists` check more readable by rewriting it as follows:

  ```
  If Not fso.FolderExists(logFileDirectory) Then
      fso.CreateFolder logFileDirectory
  End If
  ```
- Move repeated code into subroutines and functions for easier maintenance:

  ```
  Function DateTime
      DateTime = FormatDateTime(Now)
  End Function
  ...
  output = output & DateTime & " Open log file." & vbNewLine
  ```
- Usually you don't need parentheses when concatenating strings:

  ```
  output = output & DateTime & "," & i & _
      "," & Process.Name & _
      "," & Process.PercentProcessorTime & "%" & _
      "," & Process.WorkingSet   & "," & Process.PageFaultsPerSec & _
      "," & Process.PrivateBytes & "," & Process.PageFileBytes & vbNewLine
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and detailed response, Helen.  
I have tried moving the WMI objects outside the loop but the log output I see is inconsistent (processes missing, iterations skipped in the for loop).
Moving those objects outside the loop has slowed the memory leaking significantly, but it still grows, albeit slowly.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: +1 That being a very detailed answer deserves a upvote. I've vote it up more than once if i could.

Answer (score 3):

In this article, Eric Lippert (Literally worked on designing and building VBScript at Microsoft) indicates that the order in which you dispose of things may be important. Maybe you are running into one of these bugs?

I'll let you read the rest...

[When Are You Required To Set Objects To Nothing?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that's a really great article. I admit to having learned VBScript  by example from other people's terrible code, exactly as Eric described. I was always under the impression you had to set variables to nothing that were (possibly) some kind of COM allocated resource, but nice to know that's not the case, and what the real reasoning is. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against running the script in a permanent loop within the script unless you actually need such a tight loop.  I would suggest a single iteration within in the script, called from Scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the exact same issue, using it for a procmon-style attempt to capture a rogue process that appears to be respawning.

Narrowing it all down, it appears to be the **objRefresher.Refresh** and there simply appears to be no way around it

What I did to overcome this was use a for...next to run it 100 times, then immediately afterwards run the following, which would simply respawn the script and shutdown:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """", 0, False
```

So I would watch the memory crawl from 5Mb to 40Mb, then drop back down to 5Mb